# I want to start my question over. What can I do?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked a question [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/23782/what-do-readers-expect-from-a-fantasy-novel). I didn't get a satisfactory answer, and upon reflection, I think that's because I didn't word my question the way I should have. I wasn't clear enough in what I was after. I'd like to start over.

And now I have a problem. Simply editing the question won't draw in new answers (the question is fairly low down on the page by now). Asking a new question might work, but it would probably be labeled as a duplicate (which in all fairness it probably could be termed - it would be different,  but probably still too similar). And I can't delete the question, save by flagging it for such (which I suppose I could do, but I figured I'd ask here first).

What should I do when I want to 'start over' with a question?

Answer (score 5):

Editing a question bumps it up in the list of questions; go ahead and edit the question. If it still isn't getting answers, you can always assign a [bounty](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).